# Upload file from WinRT to WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, xaml, windows-runtime

Help again please. I managed to upload a file from ASP.NET to my WCF service and it works like a charm. Now I want to do the same thing from WinRT without success. My file upload service is based on this post http://www.seesharpdot.net/?p=214. From ASP.NET I upload the file using this code

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/Happy.jpg");
        string fileName = "Happy.jpg";

        ServiceReference1.FileMetaData metadata = new ServiceReference1.FileMetaData();
        metadata.LocalFilename = fileName;
        metadata.FileType = ".jpg";

        fileStream = new FileInfo(filePath).OpenRead();
        oService.UploadFile(metadata, fileStream);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
          fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, 2048);
          bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
```

From WinRT I thought this will work but it does not. No exception is thrown.

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
          openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
          openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
          openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
          openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
          openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");

          StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
          if (file != null)
          {
            byte[] bytes = await GetByteFromFile(file);
            await App.ServiceInstance.UploadFileAsync(bytes);
          }

// This is the method to convert the StorageFile to a Byte[]          
    private async Task<byte[]> GetByteFromFile(StorageFile storageFile)
    {
      var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();

      using (var dataReader = new DataReader(stream))
      {
        var bytes = new byte[stream.Size];
        await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
        dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

        return bytes;
      }
    }
```

What is interesting is that my WCF Service method only accepts a byte array (byte[]) as parameter and ignores the messageContract. Do I need to change my WCF service? How would you recommend I go about to fix this? Any help appreciated.

My WCF Service:

```
public void UploadFile(FileUploadMessage request)
    {
      Stream fileStream = null;
      Stream outputStream = null;

      try
      {
        fileStream = request.FileByteStream;

        string rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Files"); ; // ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RootPath"].ToString();
        string newFileName = Path.Combine(rootPath, request.MetaData.LocalFileName);

        outputStream = new FileInfo(newFileName).OpenWrite();
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
          outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
          bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
        throw new FaultException<IOException>(ex, new FaultReason(ex.Message));
      }
      finally
      {
        if (fileStream != null)
        {
          fileStream.Close();
        }
        if (outputStream != null)
        {
          outputStream.Close();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement the same, but the WinRT generation of the library is different as to the one for desktop (Console application).

I had to take out Mtom in the binding, and leave the WCF service parameter as a Stream type.

This still allowed me to upload the document as required. However, on the service, i named the file to the md5 checksum value. The windows 8 app then sent another message to the service, with the parameter being the md5 checksum (calculated on the WinRt device) along with the file metadata. The WCF service then looked for the file with the md5 checksum and renamed the file.

So its a 2 step process from what I see as an immediate workaround, which I think i am happy with.

Happy to share the code for the md5 checksum on the service and WinRt side if required.

Comment: Hi Looneystar. Thank you so much for your comment. Would you mind sharing your code? If you dont want to paste it here can you please email it to me at cjfranken@outlook.com. Regards

Comment: Will send the projects in an email. Wonder how i can put it here so that others can benefit out of it too maybe?